# Slow shell in OS X

Tags: python, linux, macos, shell

I wrote a little script to understand the slowyness of the OSX's shell:

```
for i in $(seq 1 1000000) ; do printf "\r$i" ; done ; echo
```

When I execute it on OSX I have this result:

```
time ./c.sh
100000
./c.sh  12.04s user 2.01s system 93% cpu 14.998 total
```

When I execute this script in a virtual machine under Linux I have this result:

```
time ./c.sh
1000000
./c.sh  1.13s user 1.52s system 64% cpu 4.074 total
```

The results are the same in an another MacBook and in a OSX virtual machine.

I tried in a minimalistic shell (/bin/sh), with login -fp as iTerm startup command and with all ASL log cleared. Results are the same.

Do you know why is OSX shell so slow and how to make it faster ? I ask my self if it was a BSD implementation of shell... so I tried in a FreeBSD and here is the result:

```
time ./c.sh
1e+06
./c.sh  1.17s user 0.84s system 44% cpu 4.542 total
```

I tried with a python script, performance between OSX & Linux are the same:

```
for i in range(0,1000000):
  print "\r" + str(i),
```

OSX:

```
$ time python c.py
999999
python c.py  0.92s user 0.18s system 60% cpu 1.799 total
```

Linux:

```
$ time python c.py
999999
python c.py  0.79s user 0.37s system 72% cpu 1.602 total
```

Reading comments, I have to add a precision: 
When I use other shell (bash from macports, zsh, sh), results are the same.

Thank you by advance for reading this.

Comment: The version of `bash` on OS X is pretty old.

Comment: OS X uses bash 3.x, Linux has bash 4.x.

Comment: Also, Bash isn't very fast at manipulating text at the character level. FWIW, this is noticeably faster than your `seq` command: `seq -s $'\r' 1000000`

Comment: Barmar:
Thank you for fast replies. I make my question more precise. I tried with other shell.

PM2Ring:
Yeah, but why a so big difference between OSX & the others Unix ?

Comment: If you do `seq 1 1000000` it takes 3.5s. If you do `seq 1 1000000 > fred.txt` it takes 0.3s. I think it is maybe slow at upating the screen rather than an inherently slow shell... anyway, you wouldn't use the shell for anything needing high performance, would you?

Comment: Yeah, It is only a test.
I have a script that grep into files in a while loop.
On Linux it take about 4 minutes, and 13 minutes on OSX.
Moreover, when I run this script as root on OSX, it take about 4 minutes too...

Comment: In Linux, are you running this under bash, or some other shell? In some distros, /bin/sh is dash (a smaller, faster shell) instead of bash. Also, try with output redirected to /dev/null to make sure it's not due to screen update speed.

Comment: I tried with bash/sh/zsh/dash on OSX & Linux.

Comment: I realize that in many of my scripts contains :

for i in $(seq 1 10000) ; do <something> ; done
# or worth:

while read line ; do <something> ; done < file

I am learning awk language and try to be better in python. I have no explication nor solution, but in fact it is not a great problem, becase as Mark Setchell, bash is not done for performance.